# Create an array with Columns?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am creating a Multithreaded application that processes data very fast, so fast that I realized that windows controls couldn't keep up, and would create issues.
So my new solution is that I am going to store results into an array and update a ListBox or ListView at the end.

Now my question is this:

In my application the user enters items into a ListBox my application then checks for these items.

How can I create an array with a column for every value in the ListBox, Adding the column name as a column header(I am guessing just add it as first value for each column).

The thing is the amount of rows would be impossible to tell before hand so it would need to be able to support any amount.

Is this a feasible idea, and if so could anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: Just use a List<>, which will grow dynamically to support however much you add to it.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante That would definitely work for me, but I can't really find much on creating a list with multiple columns.

Comment: You may want to look into the `Dictionary<>` collection

Comment: like a `List<List<>>`?  Or do you just want a datatable

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend a List of Lists, like @Jonesy suggests.

Comment: What about `DataTable`?

Comment: Why Array? use [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Wait....by "array" do you mean a grid. As in for UI?

Comment: Which would have the least overhead Dictionary<>, List<List<>> or a datatable?

Comment: You say 'multithreaded..' and 'windows controls .. create issues'. Are you aware that you can directly access a windows controls only from the main (UI-) thread?

Comment: @fast No I am not talking about crossthreading, I am talking about labels, controls, treeviews not being able to update that much data that fast.  The whole application is completely Async. It is mainly the treeview that is causing issues with my UI, but I don't think other controls will be much better, and it is not that important to have the UI so I figured I could lose some overhead by getting rid of the controls. The application is capable of making around 2 million queries in 2 hours. Which would yeild around 300 thousand lines in my treeview.

Comment: @fast It doesn't get anywhere near that before it keels over from updating too quick. I thought of updating at intervals but like I said I can get rid of the controls all together.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow I decided I am going with the DataTable. I protentially may need to Store ALOT of data, and it would make more sense if I used this due to the fact I can create a database with it easily.

Comment: and do you think to use datatable for 300.000 rows ???? how many resources it will take ? are you sure that is a right approach ? Are those data store in some place or are all in memory ? Have you take care of memory usage, object to destroy?In one of my scenarios one year ago i was started with a MTA app after few days i realized that  my application consume more than 1gb of memory to process data.Actually the same one which work with 158 databases of different site can process 2ml of row with only 185 mb. Are you sure that all is defined as well......?

Comment: @user1632018 Wise choice (points please!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest going with a `DataTable` because as a data structure it is well aligned with a database and it performs well with a large number of rows - that is kind of what it is designed for. It also allows you to apply a layer of structure onto your data that you wouldn't get with either a `List` or an `array` (under the hood a `DataTable` is not much more than an array so the performance will be comparable).